# jQuery scroll based fadeIn not waiting for scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used this code successfully before for fadeIn, animate, CSS transitions and transformations.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.item1').each(function (i) {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        /* For testing only */
        console.log(bottom_of_object);
        console.log(bottom_of_window);

        /* If the object is visible in the window */
        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

             $(this).fadeIn(1000, 'swing', function () {
                $('.item2').fadeIn(1000, 'swing', function () {
                    $('.item3').fadeIn(1000, 'swing', function () {
                        $('.item4').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    })
});
```

but I just cant get it work properly with this HTML.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 img-responsive item item1">
            <img src="images/gallery/Brows/brows13.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 img-responsive item item2">
            <img src="images/gallery/Liner/liner2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 img-responsive item item3">
            <img src="images/gallery/Body Ink/BI004.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 img-responsive item item4">
            <img src="images/gallery/Nails/nails1.png" />
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong this time.

Should have made it clearer sorry, I was in a rush to get out the door before the shops closed. The images fadeIn, but they do it on page load, not on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Your each only finds the first div (item1). Assuming you want to find them all, use

```
CSS
<style>.item4 { display: none; }</style>

jQuery
var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
$(window).scroll( function(){

$('.item1').each(function (i) {

  var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  /* For testing only */
  console.log(bottom_of_object);
  console.log(bottom_of_window);

  /* If the object is visible in the window */
  if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

     $(this).fadeIn(1000, 'swing', function () {
       $('.item2').fadeIn(10000, 'swing', function () {
          $('.item3').fadeIn(10000, 'swing', function () {
              $('.item4').fadeIn(10000, 'swing');
          });
       });
     });
  }
})
});
```

Comment: I only want to find `'.item1'` as this will start a chain of fadeIn's, which it does, but it starts on page load and disregards the scroll

Comment: Okay, I got it. All images are visible when you start the page. There could be some CSS missing. I have adjusted the code which will demonstrate fading in the 4th image.

Comment: No .item1 starts the fadeIn sequence on `$(document).ready()`. However, your answer did give me an idea. I had:

`.item {display:none;}`

but have just tried

`.item1 {display:none;}`
...
`.item4 {display:none;}`

and it worked

Comment: @Bounce. Good, .item4 was just to demonstrate.

Comment: I jumped the gun, its not working on scroll, I was scrolling faster whilst checking. The problem still remains that the `fadeIn` chain starts when the page has loaded, not on scroll.

console.log shows that `bottom_of_object` and `bottom_of_window` are working properly

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two DIVS at the end.

Always validate your HTML when you get in a quandry with something not working when it should. You can save a mountain of pain that way.

I have a feeling that you have simply forgotten to include the final two divs here, and that they appear in your own code. However, I would still say validate the page just to check.

While I am here, declare this outside of the loop:

`var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();`

You want to minimise your DOM calls as much as possible, and this isn't going to change during the duration of your loop.

Comment: The two closeing div tags are there, that was only a portion of the HMTL as I have two rows of 4 images. I have edited the question. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: And have you validated the HTML of the whole page?